# Scala Equality and HashCode

Tags: scala, hashcode, equality

[Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/) presents this code on `mutability` and `equality`.

```
class Point2(var x: Int, var y: Int) extends Equals {
def move(mx: Int, my: Int) : Unit = {
  x = x + mx
  y = y + my
}
override def hashCode(): Int = y + (31*x)

def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
  case p: Point2 => true
  case _ => false
}
override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = {
def strictEquals(other: Point2) =
  this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y
  that match {
    case a: AnyRef if this eq a => true
    case p: Point2 => (p canEqual this) && strictEquals(p)
     case _ => false
  }
}
}
```

Then, it performs evaluations.

```
scala> val x = new Point2(1,1)
x: Point2 = Point2@20
scala> val y = new Point2(1,2)
y: Point2 = Point2@21
scala> val z = new Point2(1,1)
z: Point2 = Point2@20
```

Next, a `HashMap` is created.

```
scala> val map = HashMap(x -> "HAI", y -> "WORLD")
map: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Point2,java.lang.String] =
Map((Point2@21,WORLD), (Point2@20,HAI))

scala> x.move(1,1)

scala> map(y)
res9: java.lang.String = WORLD
```

I understand that `map(x)` will return a `NoSuchElementException` since `x` has mutated. `x`'s hashCode gets re-computed due to the mutation of `x.move(1,1`). As a result, when checking if `x` is in the `map`, none of map's `hashCode`s match `x`'s new `hashCode`.

```
scala> map(x)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: Point2@40
...
```

Since `z` equals (value) the originally inserted `x` of `HashMap`, as well as the `hashCode`, why is the exception thrown?

```
scala> map(z)
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: Point2@20
```

**EDIT** This example, in my opinion, shows the **complexity** (bad) of imperative programming.

Comment: Are you sure this is the provided code? Doesn't look right.

Comment: I got from here - http://www.manning.com/suereth/SiD-Sample02.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the Map still uses `x` to test for equality.

Here is what happens:

- you insert in the map using `x` as a key, the hashCode at this time is #x. Great.
- you change some values on `x`, #x is now gone, the new hashCode is #x'.
- you try to look up the value associated to `x` in the map. The map gets the hashCode: #x'. It does not exist in the map (since at the time of insertion it was #x).
- you create `z` with the same values `x` originally had.
- you look up the value associated to `z`. The map found a value for the hashCode of `z` (since it's #x), but then calls `equals` on `z` and `x` (the same instance you used to insert the value during the first step). And you get `false` since you moved `x`!

The map keeps a reference to the instance of the key, and use it to test `equals` when you `get`, but it never re-computes the hashCode.

Comment: Thx. My former confusion came from not understanding (1) hashCode gets calculated once for a HashMap and **never** changes and (2) that map holds a reference to `x`, which is an `immutable` reference to a `mutable` data structure. Changing the data structure to which `x` ponts will change `map`'s the corresponding `key`'s object

Comment: @KevinMeredith it's not immediately obvious, but it makes sense since 2 totally unrelated (like not even the same type) objects can end up having the same hashCode so the map needs to perform another check to make sure it identified the right key. I've read the book, and if I remember correctly it's not especially well explained :)